# How to calculate a height of UITableView inside UIView?

Tags: uitableview, uiview, uiscrollview, uikit

Please advise me if I have chosen the right approach:
I need to create a view with two UILabels and a UITableView in the middle ([schematic view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6iUj.png)).
I created UIScrollView, put a contentView (UIView) on UIScrollView and put two UILabels and UITableView inside contentView.

Now I want to understand **what height of the contentView I should specify**.
Do I need to calculate the height of a UITableView and recalculate the height of the сontentView based on that?
If so, how do I correctly calculate the height of a UITableView?

Comment: Use a table view with header and footer. There is no reason to try and embed them as separate elements in a scroll view (and, that's a bad idea to begin with).

Answer (score 0):

Although I think you should use `tableHeaderView` and `tableFooterView` to solve the issue, but if you want to use `UIScrollView` nesting a `UITableView`, you could use `kvo` to get `UITableView` **contentSize** changed and `UITableView` **height** updated.